# Ansible: How to Whitelist IPs using firewalld module?

Tags: ansible

The Ansible Documentation on FirewallD is not very comprehensive. For instance How would I go about converting

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="11.22.33.44" accept' --permanent
```

to an ansible firewalld module statement in a playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/firewalld_module.html

I believe this is what you are asking for;

```
- firewalld: 
    zone=public
    rich_rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="11.22.33.44" accept'
    permanent=true
```

The ansible documentation breaks down the accepted options of the firewalld module.

You would add this section under your tasks in your playbook. The formatting might be slightly different depending on how you have your playbook laid out but I'd need to see it to know exactly.